# Identify current statement_timeout in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

How do I identify the current statement_timeout that redshift is using?  I changed it in the parameter group and it said it was in sync but it didnt seem to kick in till I rebooted the cluster.

Comment: Were you changing the cluster-wide timeout or a timeout for a queue?  Was the change in the parameters for the cluster or the definition of the queues?

Comment: Cluster wide parameter change. I don’t have queues

Answer (score 0):

Cluster wide statement_timeout is defined in the parameter group of the cluster.  Per the Redshift documentation:

> "After you modify parameter values, you must reboot any clusters that
> are associated with the modified parameter group. The cluster status
> displays applying for ParameterApplyStatus while the values are being
> applied, and then pending-reboot after the values have been applied.
> After you reboot, the databases in your cluster begin to use the new
> parameter values."

To dynamically change query timeout values you will need to change the timeout values in the queue configuration.  It sounds like you are using the default WLM configuration which defines a single user queue.  You can clone this so you can modify the values and then you can define a queue rule to terminate a query if it executes for too long.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-query-monitoring-rules.html

Comment: My thing said parameters ‘in sync’ after changing a param, not ‘applying’ or ‘pending reboot’.